Позиционирование нижнего элемента во flex контейнере
Друзья, помогите поставить кнопку в нужное место - прижать к низу, а то  у меня танцы с бубном пошли, что то упускаю.


.swiper {
  padding-top: 70px;
}

.event {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 23px;
background: var(--white);
border-radius:  30px;
}

.calendar__title {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.event__img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  background: #d9d9d9;
  border-top-left-radius:  30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

.event__content {
  padding: 0 52px 36px 52px;
}

.event__title {
font-size: 36px;
}

.event__content {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.event__content>data {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: var(--dark-grey);
}

.event__text {
  margin-bottom: 66px;
  font-size: 16px;}

.event__text>p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.event__btn {
  display: inline-block;
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid var(--red);
border-radius: 20px;
padding: 8px 30px;
color: var(--red);
font-size: 18px;
}
<!-- Slider main container -->
        <div class="swiper">
          <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
          <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <!-- Slides -->
            <div class="swiper-slide event">
              <picture>
                <img src="img/event-1.jpg" alt="event-1" class="event__img">
              </picture>
              <div class="event__content flex">
                <h3 class="title event__title">Апрель</h3>
                <data value="2024">2024</data>
                <div class="event__text">
                  <p class="event__text-p">Фонд &laquo;Подари мечту&raquo; провёл семинар для школьных психологов Абинского района.</p>
                  <p class="event__text-p">Встреча на&nbsp;тему &laquo;Как помочь школьнику выбрать профессию&raquo; прошла по&nbsp;инициативе Департамента образования района на&nbsp;базе школы N30&nbsp;в посёлке Ахтырском. Спикером мероприятия выступила профориентолог Фонда Инна Валерьевна Гончарова.</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="event__btn">Открыть</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide event">
              <picture>
                <img src="img/event-2.jpg" alt="event-2" class="event__img">
              </picture>
              <div class="event__content flex">
                <h3 class="title event__title">Март</h3>
                <data value="2024">2024</data>
                <div class="event__text">
                  <p>В&nbsp;рамках осуществления благотворительным фондом программы&nbsp;&mdash; &laquo;Я&nbsp;победитель&raquo;, были вручены гранты педагогам и&nbsp;ученикам победителям муниципального этапа Всероссийской олимпиады школьников.</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="event__btn">Открыть</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="swiper-slide event">
              <picture>
                <img src="img/event-2.jpg" alt="event-2" class="event__img">
              </picture>
              <div class="event__content">
                <h3 class="title event__title">Я победитель</h3>
                <data value="2024">Март 2024</data>
                <div class="event__text">
                  <p>В&nbsp;рамках осуществления благотворительным фондом программы&nbsp;&mdash; &laquo;Я&nbsp;победитель&raquo;, были вручены гранты педагогам и&nbsp;ученикам победителям муниципального этапа Всероссийской олимпиады школьников.</p>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="event__btn">Открыть</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- If we need pagination -->
          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

          <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>


        </div>




добавь в сниппет ссылку на библиотеку

Для начала нужно сделать карточки одной высоты

вопрос решил так: сделал карточки одинаковыми- заменили height: 100% на  height : auto у слайдов слайдера ( не совсем понимаю почему в библиотеке указано не auto).  a для блока контента Flex : 1
